# Can I add custom attributes to Active Directory schema using PowerShell only?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have a Windows Server 2016 Standard with no desktop experience installed. I want to expand the Active Directory schema with custom attributes. I can do it on a desktop environment using MMC without issues. Can I do it using PowerShell only?

Comment: Yes you can. It is highly google-able.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've tried Google but no luck. Could you direct me to any resource on Internet? What I really want to do is to modify the schema.

Comment: I googled `powershell ad change schema`. The first two hits are a two part series from the scripting guys: [Part1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/16/powershell-and-the-active-directory-schema-part-1/) [Part2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/17/powershell-and-the-active-directory-schema-part-2/)

Comment: I have to admit that I just skimmed the second part which I got from Google. When I saw the MMC screenshot I thought it was going to be the same as with a GUI. I'm really sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to look this:
http://www.rebeladmin.com/2017/11/step-step-guide-create-custom-active-directory-attributes/

should be what you need.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.